# Shared library creation in LINUX throws error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I've ten ".o" files in a directory.i want to combine them as a shared lib (.so) file.
For doing so,I am issuing following command

```
#gcc -shared *.o -o abc.so
```

but it throws following error message:

```
No command '-shared' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gshared' from package 'gshare' (universe)
-shared: command not found
```

What could be the possible reason? Anything wrong with the command?
Any help ?

Comment: Is the `*o` a typo? Didn't you mean `*.o` instead?

Comment: Also, the error message you've cited would mean that you entered `-shared *o -o abc.so`, so what's the exact string you type in? Or is this part of a script? If so, show us the part of your script that wants to call GCC.

Comment: The error shown looks like a bash error on Ubuntu - are you *sure* you typed gcc, exactly as shown?

Comment: @DarkDust: 1) updated the question, was a typo.
2) No em issuing following command directly.
#gcc -shared *.o -o abc.so

Comment: It seems that the command that is actually executed isn't the one that you think is running. Try to prefix this line with `echo`.

Comment: You could also do a `which gcc` and then go and look at the file that results. It's possible/likely your "gcc" is a wrapper script that isn't doing what you expect. I agree with the other posts, this isn't a gcc error, it's a shell error.

Comment: And you should use a builder software, like GNU `make` (or something else, like `omake`...)

Comment: If you *really* typed `#gcc -shared *.o -o abc.so` nothing would happen... since it's a comment (everything after the `#` is ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Chen Levy.  It looks like gcc is either a stange version or not what you think it is.  When I do:

```
gcc -shared *.o -o abc.so
```

I get the desired reponse.  Try echo, or even:

```
which gcc
```

to try and see what's really going on. PS: I Tested on Ubuntu 10.10